# Identify the existence of a wall like structure in a given int array

Tags: data-cleaning, dataframe, javascript, pattern-recognition

The idea is that I will query an API endpoint which will return me an array consisting of a price value and a quantity value `[price, quantity]`.

In this dataset there is high possibility that there are structure of values where there is a sudden increase in quantity for a given price range compared to the rest of its surroundings, basically a wall like structure.

Example below shows a range of price values and a quantity value as a heatmap. If I were to get a dataset of this area, I am interested in identifying the large, light colored, wall like structure. I have thought about brute forcing for every x amount of price and trying to find a sudden change in quantity and later try to look around it to find the extent of this wall but this just doesn't feel like the right approach to me.

[image: Visual]

Is there any other algorithm or way that comes to mind for searching for this kind of data? Consider that the dataset is small enough to fit into memory and there is no rate limits for pulling from the API.

Comment: It's not clear what we're looking at, what a wall is. What defines it? is it just a change of more than X, or X%? that's easy to detect. If that's not it, what is it?

Comment: What I mean by a wall is that a given set of quantity values which are higher in value relative to their surroundings but are also close in value to each other and are stored back-to-back in terms of price value. Just like the lightly coloured area in the image

Comment: Is this univariate, multivariate? I think you're just looking for peaks in the delta between successive elements. No real ML here. For more complex problems, things like FB prophet will detect 'changepoints' in time series for you, which is a more general thing that what you're seeking

Comment: The only variables here are the time, price, and quantity. So is just iterating through every price level and looking for a delta level that is considerably higher then mean delta of price levels a good strategy? I was hoping to be able to use ML to predict a possible starting and ending points of a wall like structure every second. Iterating through such data every second seems too high in the time complexity.

Comment: Ah OK you are predicting. I doubt you can predict sudden changes in price just from past prices - it must be external factors driving these anomalous jumps. That said if it is at all predictable I'd guess this is a job for RNNs

Comment: Thank you I will look into RNNs